# Why can't int (*p)[] be used as an argument for C function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, arguments, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(int (*p)[3]);
int main(void)
{
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    print(&a);

    return 0;
}
void print(int (*p)[3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(*p) / sizeof(**p); i++)
        printf("%d\n", (*p)[i]);
}
```

I have written a C function. See above.

It can print all the elements in an array.

There is one thing which is not so perfect : The number of array elements seems to be known in advance.

So I made some modification in hopes of making the function universal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(int (*p)[]);
int main(void)
{
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    print(&a);

    return 0;
}
void print(int (*p)[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(*p) / sizeof(**p); i++)
        printf("%d\n", (*p)[i]);
}
```

In the function, p is pointer pointing to the entire array.

However, it fails to be compiled.

**Why can't int (*p)[] be used as an argument for C function?**

Comment: Use just pointer. But you need to know number of elements or have some kind of terminator.

Comment: Because the type of `&a` is `int (*)[3]`, the type itself includes the size of the array, and you can not have an array without a size.

Comment: The "normal" solution to your "problem" is to pass a pointer to the first element *and* the number of elements as arguments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can have pointer to array with unknown size however

Comment: The *diagnostics messages* from the compiler must be copied into the question verbatim, otherwise this is not useful to future readers.

Comment: `int (*p)[]` is an incomplete type.  In particular, the compiler can't determine what `sizeof(*p)` is from that declaration, so things like pointer addition can't be performed.  But you shouldn't be using a pointer to an array for that function.  Just use a pointer to the first element, i.e. an `int *`, then pass it `a` instead of `&a`.  That's the normal way this is handled in C.  You only need the extra level for multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: you actually should learn a bit more about the sizeof, when it calculated and why it is a trap for the beginner programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int (*p)[]` can be used as an argument for the function. The part of your code that gives the error is `sizeof *p` which is obviously not possible, because the type of `*p` is `int[]` which is an incomplete type and hence has no known size.

For the function to know the length of the array, you must design a way for the function to receive this information. Options include:

- what you did in the original code.
- passing the length as another argument.
- including the length as an array element.
- having a sentinel value on the end of the array.

The most common idiom would be to pass `int *p, size_t n`, you do not really gain anything by using pointer-to-array without the dimension being given.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `int []` is an incomplete type as the array has no defined size and therefore its `sizeof` cannot be taken.

In "modern C" (i.e. for almost 2 decades) you could have used variable-length arrays for this - you can pass the size as an argument and then the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(size_t n, int (*p)[*]);

int main(void) {
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    print(3, &a);
}

void print(size_t n, int (*p)[n]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(*p) / sizeof(**p); i++)
        printf("%d\n", (*p)[i]);
}
```

Of course this gains you nothing, since `sizeof *p / sizeof **pp` will be ... `n`.  Therefore we might as well have used

```
void print(size_t n, int p[n]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < p; i++)
        printf("%d\n", p[i]);
}
```

which is less typing.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `int (*p)[]` can't be used as an argument and have the function magically know the array size, because the standard says so.

Longer answer:

`int (*p)[]` is a pointer to an array, but the array has no defined size. So by looking at the array, it is impossible to do pointer arithmetic, calculate size of the thing p is pointing at, etc..

You don't have array of arrays so you don't need `int (*p)[]`. You have an array of int, so `int *p` or `int p[]` should be enough. This does not solve the problem of knowing the size of your array in `print`. To do this you basically have 3 options

1. Hardcode the value in the function
2. Put a sentinel value in your array to  mark the end
3. Pass the size as a separate parameter like this:

   void print(int n, int p[n])

Just remember that whatever method you use, parameter passing of arrays will always use pointers behind the scenes, so you CAN NOT use `sizeof(p)` to calculate the size of the array. `sizeof` will always return the size of a pointer in those situations

Comment: @M.M yes you are right, it can be used as parameter, but not the way OP was using it. Shall edit the answer to reflect that